# dropzone options not working with knockout

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, dropzone.js

When I use [dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) without knockout binding, It works fine but when I use knockout binding it works but does not apply settings (options like autoProcessQueue: false).

My HTML code is:

```
<form id="my-awesome-dropzone" class="dropzone" action="@Url.Action("FileUploadHandler", "Electronics")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div data-bind="text:name"></div>
    <input type="text" name="myName" />
     <div id="dropzonePreview" class="dz-default dz-message">
    </div>
</form>
```

My Js code is:

```
function VM() {
            var self = this;
            self.name = ko.observable("Irfan");
        };
        $(document).ready(function () {
            ko.applyBindings(new VM());
            Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = { 

                autoProcessQueue: false,
                uploadMultiple: true,
                parallelUploads: 100,
                maxFiles: 100,
                addRemoveLinks: true,
                clickable:'#dropzonePreview',
                init: function () {
                    var myDropzone = this;
                    this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        myDropzone.processQueue();
                    });
              }
       }
```

Comment: My first inclination is that it's worth checking to see what your DOM looks like between the applyBindings call and the Dropzone options setting.  I haven't used Dropzone a great deal but, IIRC, in my code I wrote a binding handler to hook things together.  A quick google finds gists like https://gist.github.com/csim/4513ae3316104e6f474d which could help point you in the right direction.